# Openshift MySql no class found exception in runnable jar

Tags: java, mysql, jar, jboss, openshift

I am trying deploying a runnable JAR file on Openshift server, my runnable JAR file contains a cron job, its functionality is to read data from database at certain time I place mysql-connector-jar in my JAR file and deployed on my openshift application, when running I am getting following exception. In my cron job.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource
    at com.fs.sstore.communicator.cronjob.db.DataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:46)
    at com.fs.sstore.communicator.cronjob.db.DBManager.fetchScheduleRecharges(DBManager.java:29)
    at com.fs.sstore.communicator.cronjob.RechargeScheduler.scheduleRecharge(RechargeScheduler.java:15)
    at com.fs.sstore.communicator.cronjob.RechargeScheduler.<init>(RechargeScheduler.java:9)
    at com.fs.sstore.communicator.cronjob.RechargeScheduler.main(RechargeScheduler.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: do any one got this exception?

Comment: How are you packaging your runnable jar ?

Comment: runnable jar set with exporting required libraries into generated jar